# select rows from a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I would like to separate training and test data from a data frame and display the graphics and then make some other changes, but I'm not sure how to select them within my data frame.

how can i use the loop for to do them all at once

[image]

I created a list with the values ​​of the 'Código' column

```
df_pl_drop = df_pl['Código'].drop_duplicates()
list = df_pl_drop.tolist()
```

just below is a code I created to separate the data but I can only do it manually by selecting a specific value.

```
df_plc = df_pl['Código'] == 'RRRP3'
df_pl = df_pl[df_plc]
```

[image]

How can I use the for loop to automatically select the values ​​and separate the data and later do some other change and manipulation of that data

Comment: What do you want to do? Random sampling, stratified random sampling or something else? You can use `train_test_split` from `sklearn` for the first two (note: returns numpy arrays)

Comment: I intend to do some other manipulations later but I have to separate the data frame this way first, but I don't know a method to use a loop to navigate the list inside the data frame

Comment: From your description I think you want to separate your original dataframe into smaller dataframes by values in the `Codigo` column. You can get a dictionary of those smaller dataframes with this `dict(list(df.groupby('Codigo')))`